# Limiting FTP privileges on Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ftp, file-sharing

I currently have a Windows 2012 Server which is acting as a webserver running IIS.
I am using Filezilla to host an FTP server to allow *some* clients FTP access to their own websites.

I have setup the FTP account with ease and they are able to access their website folder. However I really wish to explore this further and actually make this secure. At the moment there is nothing stopping them uploading .exe file and run on the website, to hack my server.

**How can I limit the files they upload to just a few desired extensions such as PHP, JS as well as disabling renaming of entities (to stop them changing back the extention to .exe as an example).
Additionally, are there any other security measures I could take?**

Please tell me if I missed any information. Please do not reply with comments such as "If you don't trust them, dont give access" as this is off topic

Answer (score 0):

In reality it depends from FTP service application - ie what Filezilla allows.

But You can try to install File Server Resource Manager (feature under File and Storage Services)  and use File Screens. It should allow blocking files by types (extensions). It should block creating files on OS level, not sure what Filezilla does when OS blocks file write.